# How can I have CodeIgniter load specific pages using SSL?

Tags: php, apache, ssl, codeigniter, https

How can I have CodeIgniter load specific pages using SSL? I have an apache2/`mode_ssl` server. `mod_ssl` uses a different document root than non-secure pages. For example, https (port 443) would serve pages out of `/var/www/ssl_html/` And http (port 80) serves pages out of `/var/www/html/`. How would I get CodeIgniter to play nice with this setup?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

There are few ways to tackle this.

**Option 1:**

I would probably have the code deployed to both folders, then in the file: /system/application/config/config.php, set your page to:

```
$config['base_url'] = "http://www.yoursite.com/";
```

or

```
$config['base_url'] = "https://www.yoursite.com/";
```

Then in your non-ssl VirtualHost folder, set your config to redirect protected pages by folder to the SSL site:

```
RedirectPermanent /sslfolder https://www.yoursite.com/sslfolder
```

**Option 2:**

Send everything to SSL and keep all your code in one folder

/system/application/config/config.php, set your page to:

```
$config['base_url'] = "https://www.yoursite.com/";
```

**Other Options**

There are some more hacky ways to do this with header() redirects, etc. but I don't think you want to maintain different code bases for this option. I don't recommend this but you could do something like:

```
$config['base_url'] = “http://” . $_SERVER['http_host'] . “/”;
```

Comment: Thanks. I think I'm gonna go with the first option and then rewrite the url_help to handle https.

Comment: The simple answer is to set ``$config['base_url']`` to empty string, as in ``='';`` - CodeIgniter will autodetect everything basing on the URL. As a result, you can arbitrary open any page with or without SSL, just by typing the URL. No need to split content between ssl and non_ssl directories on your server.

Comment: just FYI, this `$config['base_url'] = “http://” . $_SERVER['http_host'] . “/”;` is wrong, it should be `$config['base_url'] = 'https://' . $_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"] . '/';`    Syntax is wrong and $_SERVER["http_host"] (lower case) doesn't exist...

Answer (score 11):

In application/config/config.php, set base_url to:

`$config['base_url'] = ($_SERVER['SERVER_PORT'] == 443 ? 'https' : 'http') . "://{$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']}/";`

This will allow it to work on any domain, which is convenient if you test locally.

Comment: I used this successfully in combination with: 
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} =off
RewriteRule ^my-secure-url-segment https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
in my .htaccess file.

Comment: Didn't worked for me, $_SERVER['SERVER_PORT'] for me is 80  ; HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PORT is 443

Answer (score 6):

I put following lines in ./application/config/config.php file and it works perfectly:

```
$protocol = ( isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && $_SERVER['HTTPS'] == 'on' ) ? 'https' : 'http';
$config['base_url'] = $protocol.'://www.yoursite.com';
```

Answer (score 3):

I would maintain two sets of the code and handle a forced redirect to HTTPS pages with a post_controller_constructor hook. The hook will be called before each page is rendered to check if the visitor should be redirected to HTTPS based on their current location on your site.

STEP 1

Create file: system/application/hooks/SecureAccount.php

```
<?php

class SecureAccount
{
    var $obj;

    //--------------------------------------------------
    //SecureAccount constructor
    function SecureAccount()
    {
        $this->obj =& get_instance();
    }

    //--------------------------------------------------
    //Redirect to https if in the account area without it
    function index()
    {
        if(empty($_SERVER["HTTPS"]) || $_SERVER["HTTPS"] !== 'on')
        {
            $this->obj =& get_instance();
            $this->obj->load->helper(array('url', 'http'));

            $current = current_url();
            $current = parse_url($current);

            if((stripos($current['path'], "/account/") !== false))
            {
                $current['scheme'] = 'https';

                redirect(http_build_url('', $current), 'refresh');
            }
        }
    }
}
?>
```

STEP 2

Customize the path in the function for which areas of your site should be forced to use HTTPS.

STEP 3

Add the following to system/application/config/hooks.php

```
/* Force HTTPS for account area */
$hook['post_controller_constructor'] = array(
                                'class'    => 'SecureAccount',
                                'function' => 'index',
                                'filename' => 'SecureAccount.php',
                                'filepath' => 'hooks',
                                'params'   => array()
                                );
```

Answer (score 2):

I can easily, I only define:

```
$config['base_url'] = '';
```

CI get base_url automaticaly =D

Comment: No longer recommended, just FYI.

Comment: yeah, CI3 in the config.php it says "MUST NOT be used in production!"

Comment: This "tip" worked well on CI2 about 2014, I don't know for another CI versions, but I never had problems and warning :)

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem with in config.php

```
$config['ssl_active'] = false;
if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && $_SERVER['HTTPS'] !== 'off' || $_SERVER['SERVER_PORT'] == 443) {
    $config['ssl_active'] = true;
}

$config['base_url'] = ($config['ssl_active'] === true )?"https":"http" . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
```

The directory trouble, you can use a simple simbolic link ln -s

Answer (score 0):

This is what worked for me.
Our server both have **$_SERVER['SERVER_PORT']** and **$_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PORT']**

We should check first if **$_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PORT']** is available and use this instead of $_SERVER['SERVER_PORT']

```
$config['base_url'] =
( ( ( empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PORT']) ? $_SERVER['SERVER_PORT'] : $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PORT'] ) == 443 ? 'https' : 'http') . "://" . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] )
. str_replace(basename($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']),"",$_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']) ;
```

tested this on our linux server...

---

btw, it's based on skyler's answer before which was.

```
$config['base_url'] = ($_SERVER['SERVER_PORT'] == 443 ? 'https' : 'http') . "://{$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']}/";
```

Comment: The previous answers doesn't maintain script_name if CI is deployed on a subdirectory, we need to preserve this. str_replace(basename($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']),"",$_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'])

Answer (score 0):

the solution that came to my mind is to use str_replace() like so

```
$base_url_str = base_url(); 
$secure_base_url = str_replace("http","https",$base_url_str );
```

whenever I need a secure location , i use $secure_base_url instead of base_url(),
so let's say your base_url() is http://www.example.com then $secure_base_url will be https://www.example.com

Answer (score 0):

another [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8657428/codeigniter-redirect-not-preserving-https-in-relative-redirects) is similar to this

you can use a **protocol-relative url** which will keep persistence in the linking in CI.

in your `config.php` instead of:

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://example.com/';
```

put;

```
$config['base_url'] = '//example.com/';
```

information about protocol-relative links [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_Resource_Locator#Protocol-relative_URLs).

Answer (score -1):

Here's a good solution.
http://sajjadhossain.com/2008/10/27/ssl-https-urls-and-codeigniter/

Comment: When providing answers you should include methods/examples in your actual answer. If your link is ever removed, your answer will become entirely useless.