# Forcing SSL in codeigniter with a helper

Tags: .htaccess, codeigniter, ssl

I am trying to adopt a ssl routing solution to my shopping cart app so that certain pages are "forced" to be https:// pages and visa-verse.  Through research I have come across many solutions which involve the use of code either in a helper, a hook or in a controller. I have tried a few of these solutions and in each, I get a redirect error when switching to an https:// page.

Here is the last version I have tried (found here: http://nigel.mcbryde.com.au/2009/03/working-with-ssl-in-codeigniter):

Create a file in application/helper called ssl_helper.php

```
if (!function_exists('force_ssl'))
{
    function force_ssl()
    {
        $CI =& get_instance();
        $CI->config->config['base_url'] =
                 str_replace('http://', 'https://',
                 $CI->config->config['base_url']);
        if ($_SERVER['SERVER_PORT'] != 443)
        {
            redirect($CI->uri->uri_string());
        }
    }
}

function remove_ssl()
{
    $CI =& get_instance();
    $CI->config->config['base_url'] =
                  str_replace('https://', 'http://',
                  $CI->config->config['base_url']);
    if ($_SERVER['SERVER_PORT'] != 80)
    {
        redirect($CI->uri->uri_string());
    }
}
```

Load the helper, then in the constructor for any controller that requires ssl, simply insert:

```
force_ssl();
```

In every controller that you don’t want to have ssl put:

```
if (function_exists('force_ssl')) remove_ssl();
```

As stated above, when using this, I get stuck in a redirect loop and get an error (though the url has the https:// as it should).  Could my problem be in my .htaccess file?  Here is my .htaccess file:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine On
   RewriteBase /store
   RewriteCond $1 !^(index.php\.php|resources|robots\.txt)
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

I've been at this for over a week now!  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I answered a similar question [here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1500527/how-to-use-ssl-with-codeigniter/1500558#1500558](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1500527/how-to-use-ssl-with-codeigniter/1500558#1500558)

But, in a nutshell:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine On
   RedirectPermanent /sslfolder https://www.yoursite.com/sslfolder
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Thanks, I saw this solution during my research.  I may use this solution to just make the entire cart app https, if I can't get this working as others seem to have.  I prefer to have one folder.

Comment: used your solution to make the entire cart https

Comment: It causes more CPU load, but seems to me to always be the right way to go.

Answer (score 2):

here is the solution for the redirect loop if you use force_ssl function.

```
function check_ssl()
{
    $CI =& get_instance();
    $class = $CI->router->fetch_class();       
    $ssl = array('Register', 'SignIn', 'Recover');        
    if(in_array($class, $ssl))
    {
        force_ssl();
    }
    else
    {
        unforce_ssl();
    }
}
function force_ssl()
{        
    $CI =& get_instance();
    $CI->config->set_item('base_url', str_replace('http://', 'https://', config_item('base_url'))); 
    if ($_SERVER['SERVER_PORT'] != 443) // it will loop if you change it to !==
    {
        redirect($CI->uri->uri_string());
    }
}
function unforce_ssl()
{
    $CI =& get_instance();
    $CI->config->set_item('base_url', str_replace('https://', 'http://', config_item('base_url')));
    if ($_SERVER['SERVER_PORT'] != 80) // it will loop if you change it to !==
    {
        redirect($CI->uri->uri_string());
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi guys check by answer here by setting base_url in config it will automatically switch between http and https

[force ssl without helper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11483312/force-ssl-in-codeigniter/11489869#11489869)