# Codeigniter: How can I encrypt password before submitting the form to the controller?

Tags: php, security, codeigniter, encryption, passwords

I have a simple `html` login form

```
<form method="post" action="http://www.example.com/login">
    <input type="text" name="text_box" />
    <input type="password" name="pass_word" />
    <input type="submit" name="submit">
</form>
```

when I submit the form and in the controller

```
public function login(){
    $pass_word = $this->input->post('pass_word');
    die($pass_word);
}
```

The problem here, it shows the plain password, if I type `123456` in controller , I get `123456`.

1. Is this a security issue?
2. Can any one get my password through a network monitoring tool like `wireshark`?

how to avoid this? Can I encrypt the password in view, before send to the controller?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_Layer_Security

Comment: Use javascript for that... you can google a simple md5 encryption script. Just encode the password on form submit.

Comment: @vishal , if i encrypt the password you can see the js and check what is the method i have used to do the encryption , and i think you can decrypt it

Comment: @Lefters , can you suggest me a link of an example

Comment: @KanishkaPanamaldeniya I suggested MD5; that's a one way hashing algorithm, it produces a hash that cannot be reversed(you cannot revert a hash back to the original string anyway) [MD5](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Md5).

Comment: @KanishkaPanamaldeniya, I've posted an answer that hopefully will be of some use

Comment: @Vishal: client-side processing doesn't solve the problem. If an attacker has man-in-the-middle they can alter the .js as it is served to the consumer, and purloin the input without hashing it.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If your post data (password etc.) was intercepted, then it would just be visible as plaintext. Using SSL/HTTPS will provide encryption for the data that you send. I wouldn't rely on client-side JavaScript or anything similar for the purposes for authenticating / logging in a user. It's likely to give your users more confidence too, seeing that a secure connection is being used.

First, I'd just read up about SSL and HTTPS in general, as well as SSL certificates - Wiki, Google and SO would all be be good places to look, there's loads of information out there.

For using SSL/HTTPS with CI, I found these useful:

- http://sajjadhossain.com/2008/10/27/ssl-https-urls-and-codeigniter/
- http://nigel.mcbryde.com.au/2009/03/working-with-ssl-in-codeigniter/
- [How can I have CodeIgniter load specific pages using SSL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1500527/how-to-use-ssl-with-codeigniter)

In particular the force ssl function from [Nigel's post](http://nigel.mcbryde.com.au/2009/03/working-with-ssl-in-codeigniter/):

> Create a file in application/helper called ssl_helper.php

```
if (!function_exists('force_ssl'))
{
    function force_ssl()
    {
        $CI =& get_instance();
        $CI->config->config['base_url'] =
                 str_replace('http://', 'https://',
                 $CI->config->config['base_url']);
        if ($_SERVER['SERVER_PORT'] != 443)
        {
            redirect($CI->uri->uri_string());
        }
    }
}

function remove_ssl()
{
    $CI =& get_instance();
    $CI->config->config['base_url'] =
                  str_replace('https://', 'http://',
                  $CI->config->config['base_url']);
    if ($_SERVER['SERVER_PORT'] != 80)
    {
        redirect($CI->uri->uri_string());
    }
}
```

> Load the helper, then in the constructor for any controller that
>   requires ssl, simply insert:
>
> `force_ssl();`
>
> In every controller that you don’t want to have ssl put:
>
> `if (function_exists('force_ssl')) remove_ssl();`

This is a programmatic approach, another way would be to use .htaccess (if you're using Apache).

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it's definitely a security issue. Like you say, anyone with Wireshark (or similar) has the potential to intercept it.

This probably isn't something you want to rely on JavaScript for. Generally you'd use something like SSL/HTTPS, there's a blog post (a little old) detailing how to go about it with CodeIgniter, however it's pretty common so you might be able to find a more recent tutorial with a bit of Googling.

http://sajjadhossain.com/2008/10/27/ssl-https-urls-and-codeigniter/
http://nigel.mcbryde.com.au/2009/03/working-with-ssl-in-codeigniter/.

UPDATE:
Lefter's answer provides more detail and is correct, please view it as well/instead

Answer (score 1):

Go through http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/encryption.html . Everything about the encryption and decryption is described here.

Performs the data encryption and returns it as a string. Example:

```
$pass_word = $this->encrypt->encode(input->post('pass_word'));
```

Decrypts an encoded string. Example:

```
$encrypted_pass_word = 'APANtByIGI1BpVXZTJgcsAG8GZl8pdwwa84';

$plaintext_pass_word = $this->encrypt->decode($encrypted_pass_word);
```

You can optionally pass your encryption key via the second parameter if you don't want to use the one in your config file. Go through the link to read the detail explanation about it.

Comment: yes , i can do encryption in the controller , the problem is some one can get the password in the middle of the post request ?????

Comment: SSL is the only answer to this. Everything else can be snooped or just done by looking at your Javascript. SSL is designed for this; if you're asking this question you definitely shouldn't be trying to come up with a better solution!

Answer (score 1):

```
$password = sha1($this->input->post('password'));

or 

$hash= $this->input->post('password');

$password= $this->encrypt->sha1($hash);
```

> you can use **md5** instead of **sha1** but **sha1** is more **secure** then **md5**... and
>   both **md5 & sha1**  are **non-decodable**

Answer (score 0):

There is a more easy way to user https.

I put following lines in ./application/config/config.php file and it works perfectly:

```
$protocol = ( isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && $_SERVER['HTTPS'] == 'on' ) ? 'https' : 'http';
$config['base_url'] = $protocol.'://www.yoursite.com';
```

Comment: May be it is very easy and simple process.