# Codeigniter https page on site

Tags: php, codeigniter, paypal

I have built a bespoke site in Codeigniter and my client is getting orders through PayPal.

The problem that is happening is that I have written the site so that if a PayPal order is complete and **returns** back to the site, The booking gets updated to paid.

I have noticed that some orders, The customer is not returning to the site due sometimes the "Insecure Data" popup you get in most browsers.

I think, The way to resolve this is to make the return page an https:// page.

So am wondering how do you change the config in your CI to the https:// link on just that one page.

There may be other ways and am open to suggestions.

I am also considering the IPN route to update the order, But not too sure on that one.

Thanks

Comment: i have tried this  http://www.davidnard.com/2011/04/easy-ssl-redirection-in-codeigniter/

Comment: Nice, seems like a good answer. Applying the SSL to my Bookings controller.

Comment: I found that this had already been answered here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1500527/how-can-i-have-codeigniter-load-specific-pages-using-ssl/1500558#1500558

Comment: my suggestion would be to allow customers to enter the store on http - but then all the links are https. because really even your shipping form should be on https to protect peoples information.

Comment: @cartalot Fair point, I have a "Bookings" controller and I think that should all be https://

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use MY_url_helper helper.
Add the following code to helper and use it whereever you want to force ssl.

```
<?php

function ssl_support() {
    $CI = & get_instance();
    return $CI->config->item('ssl_support');
}

if (!function_exists('force_ssl')) {

    function force_ssl() {
        if (ssl_support() && (!isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) || $_SERVER['HTTPS'] == 'off')) {
            $CI = & get_instance();
            $CI->config->config['base_url'] = str_replace('http://', 'https://', $CI->config->config['base_url']);
            redirect($CI->uri->uri_string());
        }
    }

}

if (!function_exists('remove_ssl')) {

    function remove_ssl() {
        if (isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && $_SERVER['HTTPS'] == 'on') {
            $CI = & get_instance();
            $CI->config->config['base_url'] = str_replace('https://', 'http://', $CI->config->config['base_url']);

            redirect($CI->uri->uri_string());
        }
    }

}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would say put everything in one folder and use SSL for everhting?

application/config/config.php, set base url:

```
$config['base_url'] = "https://www.yoursite.com/";
```

Comment: Hi @chillion this doesnt seem too bad an idea! Would make setting things up easier